# Verifying the divergence theorem: over B

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, divergence-theorem

Let $B$ be the region of $\mathbb{R}^3$

$$B = \{ (x,y,z) |\  x+y+z \le 1,\ x\geq0,\ y\geq0,\ z\geq0 \}$$
and $\mathbf{F}$ be the field $$\mathbf{F}(x,y,z) = (x,y,z)$$

My guess was use spherical coordinates for the triple integral, I integrate $3*\rho^2* \sin(\phi)$, which is the result of the divergence of $\mathbf{F}$ with $0\leq \theta\leq1/2\pi$, $0\leq\phi\leq1/2\pi$ and $0\leq\rho\leq1$ but it didn't work.
 Maybe it can be even easier and for the other part of the theorem the sum of the double integrals I've got 2 surfaces the $z\geq0$ and $z\le1-x-y$ but didn't gave me the same result as triple integral.
For the first one I integrate from  $0\leq \theta\leq1/2\pi$, $0\leq\phi\leq1/2\pi$  $\cos(\phi)*\sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta$
and gave me $\pi/4$, for the $x+z+y \le 1 $ I integrate $0\leq \theta\leq1/2\pi$, $0\leq\phi\leq1/2\pi$  $\sin(\phi) d\phi d\theta$
and gave me $\pi/2$ the sum is $3 \pi/4$ while the triple is $\pi/2$

Comment: $B$ is a certain region bounded by planes. I suggest you draw it carefully; then it's volume will be very easy to figure out. Also if you say you don't get the same answers you should include your computations.

Comment: I just erased every single integral I did, I'm doing this from zero again, just posted the regions I considered previusly

Comment: @peek-a-boo just uploaded it!

Comment: For a region bounded by planes, spherical is definitely not the way to go. Cartesian will serve you much better.